# Конец света, календарь майя (исходники)

Tags: java, c++, алгоритм

Задолбала истерия по-поводу конца света и решил залезть таки в Яндекс и прочитать по-поводу всего этого балагана и обнаружил что вся эта истерия зиждется на [календаре майя](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%E0%EB%E5%ED%E4%E0%F0%FC_%EC%E0%E9%FF), цикл которого довольно сложен и в итоге приводит к более точному определению длительности суток.

Теперь собственно вопрос - все мы знаем тучу реализаций Грегорианского или Юлианского календарей, а есть где-то реализация календаря майя? Язык не сильно важен, лучше конечно Java, но C# или С/С++ тоже подойдут.

Хотел, как говорится, кое-какие вычисления сделать :)

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Вот только кому это может понадобиться?

Кстати, почему бы Вам его не реализовать, если не найдется готовое решение?

Comment: Понадобиться может Жрецам Майя.

Comment: Имплементировать надо поскорее, 3 дня всего осталось :)

Comment: @barmaley - это живой пример, как на вопросах неочем набрать респекта :) люди любят поговорить неочем, насчет конца света - видел на днях программка для дрончика, дает советы как подготовится к концу, так за 2 дня, больше 10к закачек

Comment: http://lipetsk.moe-online.ru/image/user/image/21639_s1.jpg

Comment: `class MayaCalendar extends Calendar` всего-то 7 методов вкрутить :)

Comment: Да совершенно точно все сказал @Gorets - вопрос чисто пиарный: цель только привлечение внимания к ресурсу. Просто в последнее время мало хороших вопросов - скучно как то... Если кто-то реально думает, что я на этом зарабатываю себе баллы, глубоко ошибается :)

Answer (score 7):

Ога вот и исходники подоспели. Ушлые ребята уже подсуетились [составили календарь](http://code.google.com/p/maya-calendar-android/source/browse/trunk/MayaCalendar/src/org/maya/calendar/model/MayaCalendar.java?spec=svn12&r=12) успели [сгенерировать аппы](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=mayan+calendar) и сорвали банк :). Молодцы!

```
package org.maya.calendar.model;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/** 
 * Translates Gregorian <=> Maya calendar based on correlation point specified in constructor. 
 * Example:
 * <pre>
 * MayaCalendar mc = MayaCalendar.create (MayaCalendar.GMT_CORRELATION);
 * mc.set (7,16,6,16,18);
 * String gregorianDate = mc.toGregorianDate();
 * </pre>
 */ 
public class MayaCalendar {

    /** 
     * GMT (Goodman - Martinez - Thompson) correlation.
     * Most commonly accepted according to Wikipedia. 
     */
    public static final int GMT_CORRELATION = 584283;

    /** GMT+2 correlation (AKA Thompson - Lounsbury).
     * most commonly accepted according to M.Coe */
    public static final int THOMPSON_LOUNSBURY = 584285; //

    private static final long MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY = 24L *60*60*1000;

    private final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("d MMM, yyyy G");
    private final Calendar greatCycleStartDate;

    private int daysSinceGreatCycle;

    /** Constructs an instance of MayaCalendar based on given correlation number. */
    public static MayaCalendar create(int correlationNumber) {
        Calendar c = getJulianDate();

        c.add (Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, correlationNumber);

        return new MayaCalendar(c);
    }

    private static Calendar getJulianDate() {
        //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day_number => 12:00 January 1, 4713 BC, Monday
        TimeZone mx = TimeZone.getTimeZone("MX"); // Mexico/Yucatan
        GregorianCalendar c = (GregorianCalendar) Calendar.getInstance(mx);

        // Switching to proleptic Gregorian calendar used by most Maya scholars (extend Georgian calendar prior to 1581)
        //c.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)); 
        c.set(Calendar.ERA, GregorianCalendar.BC);
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 4713);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @param correlationPoint Correlation point, beginning of the last Great Cycle in Maya calendar
     * 
     * @see #create(int)
     * 
     */
    public MayaCalendar (Calendar correlationDate) {
        this.greatCycleStartDate = correlationDate;

        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MX"));
    }

    public int getDaysSinceGreatCycle() {
        return daysSinceGreatCycle;
    }

    /** parses Date specified in Long Count format, e.g. "12.19.19.17.19" */ 
    public void parseLongCountDate (String longCountDate) {
        String [] components = longCountDate.split("\\.");
        try {
            if (components.length != 5)
                throw new Exception("Expecting 5 numbers separated by dots");
            int baktuns = Integer.valueOf(components[0]);
            int katuns = Integer.valueOf(components[1]);
            int tuns = Integer.valueOf(components[2]);
            int winals = Integer.valueOf(components[3]);
            int kins = Integer.valueOf(components[4]);
            set (baktuns, katuns, tuns, winals, kins);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid long count date format: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /** Set date to given long count date */
    public void set (int baktuns, int katuns, int tuns, int uinals, int kins) {
        assert MayaTimeUnit.Kin.toDays (1) == 1;
        daysSinceGreatCycle =
            MayaTimeUnit.Baktun.toDays (baktuns) +
            MayaTimeUnit.Katun.toDays(katuns) +
            MayaTimeUnit.Tun.toDays(tuns) +
            MayaTimeUnit.Winal.toDays(uinals) +
            kins;
    }

    /** Set date to a given Gregorian/Julian calendar date */
    public void set (Calendar c) {
        //long nDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(c.getTimeInMillis() - correlationPoint.getTimeInMillis());
        long nDays = (c.getTimeInMillis() - greatCycleStartDate.getTimeInMillis()) / MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY;

        if (nDays < 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("Date is too small " + c.getTime());
        if (nDays > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            throw new RuntimeException("Date is too large " + c.getTime());

        daysSinceGreatCycle = (int) nDays; 
    }

    /** @return Long count format int[5] = { baktun, katun, tun, winal, tin } */
    public int[] toLongCount () {

        int [] result = new int [5];
        int date = daysSinceGreatCycle;
        result [MayaTimeUnit.Baktun.ordinal()] = date / MayaTimeUnit.Baktun.numberOfDays; // baktuns 
        date = date % MayaTimeUnit.Baktun.numberOfDays;

        result [MayaTimeUnit.Katun.ordinal()] = date / MayaTimeUnit.Katun.numberOfDays; // katun
        date = date % MayaTimeUnit.Katun.numberOfDays;

        result [MayaTimeUnit.Tun.ordinal()] = date / MayaTimeUnit.Tun.numberOfDays; // tun
        date = date % MayaTimeUnit.Tun.numberOfDays;

        result[MayaTimeUnit.Winal.ordinal()] = date / MayaTimeUnit.Winal.numberOfDays; // winal
        result[MayaTimeUnit.Kin.ordinal()] = date % MayaTimeUnit.Winal.numberOfDays; // kin

        return result;
    }

    /** @return day name number in Tzolk'in calendar, e.g. it returns 0 (Ajaw) for the day "4 Ajaw" */
    public Tzolkin toTzolkinDayName () {
        // The Tzolk'in date is counted forward from 4 Ajaw.
        return Tzolkin.DAYS[(daysSinceGreatCycle + 19) % 20]; // relative to Ajaw
    }

    /** @return day number in Tzolk'in calendar, e.g. it returns 4 for the day "4 Ajaw" */
    public int toTzolkinDayNumber () {
        // The Tzolk'in date is counted forward from 4 Ajaw.
        return (daysSinceGreatCycle + 4) % 13;
    }

    /** @return day name number in Haab calendar, e.g. it returns Yaxkin (5) for the day "14 Yaxk'in" */
    public Haab toHaabDayName () {
        int d = (daysSinceGreatCycle + 349) % 365;
        return Haab.DAYS[d / 20]; 
    }

    /** @return day number in Haab calendar, e.g. it returns 14 for the day "14 Yaxk'in" */
    public int toHaabDayNumber () {
        int d = (daysSinceGreatCycle + 349) % 365;
        return d % 20 - 1;
    }

    /** @return Long count representation of currently set date (e.g. "7.16.6.16.18") */
    public String toLongCountString () {
        int [] lc = toLongCount();
        return String.valueOf(lc[0]) + '.' + lc[1] + '.' + lc[2] + '.' + lc[3] + '.' + lc[4];
    }

    /** @return Gregorian calendar representation of currently set date  */
    public String toGregorianString () {
        Calendar c = toGregorianDate ();
        return format.format(c.getTime());
    }

    /** @return Converts currently defined date into Gregorian calendar */
    public Calendar toGregorianDate () {
        Calendar c = (Calendar)greatCycleStartDate.clone();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, daysSinceGreatCycle);
        return c;
    }

    public int getCorrelationNumber () {
        Calendar julianDate = getJulianDate();
        Calendar date = toGregorianDate();
        return (int) (( date.getTimeInMillis() - julianDate.getTimeInMillis()) / MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY );
    }

    public String toString () {
        return format.format(greatCycleStartDate.getTime()) + " + " + String.valueOf(daysSinceGreatCycle);
    }
}
```